# How to call method using constructor

Tags: swing

I am trying to retrieve data from database and display it using label in java swing. Here are my codes :

```
    public void SetUpJTable() {
    // Set Up Database Source
    db.setUp("IT Innovation Project");
    String sql = "Select topic_title,topic_description,topic_by from forumTopics WHERE topic_id = "
            + topicId + "";
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    // Call readRequest to get the result
    resultSet = db.readRequest(sql);
    try {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            jLabel_topicTitle.setText(resultSet.getString("topic_title"));
            jLabel_content.setText(resultSet.getString("topic_description"));
            jLabel_topicBy.setText(resultSet.getString("topic_by"));
        }
        resultSet.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

And I used a constructor to call the method :

```
        public eForumThreadContent(){
    SetUpJTable();
    };
```

However, when I run the app, the label is not showing anything. So how can I fix this? I have no idea how to call a method in a class which is without main method. Any guides? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) or at least a more complete code.

Comment: _I have no idea how to call a method in a class which is without main method._ Then please stop doing this and learn how to call methods from different classes. This can be done easily afterwards.

Comment: I try to do like when user enter this forum thread, the topic details will be showed. That's the complete code to retrieve topic details. The rests of my codes are for replies.

Comment: The label is not showing anything when user first enter the page.

Comment: You never set `db` to any value. Or is that a class? If so, you should **really** use the Java naming conventions (in short: classes/types use PascalCase, methods/fields/variables use camelCase).

Comment: ya db is a class to set up the odbc driver

Answer (score 0):

To call method from other class:

```
    public class Class1
    {
        public static void methodFromClass1()
        {
            // body...
        }
    }

    public class Class2
    {
        Class1.methodFromClass1(); // thats the way you do it.
    }
```

Ass you can see Class2 has no main class.. You can also call `methodFromClass1()` in Class1 the same way. But it's all in the manuals..

Comment: No no. I am calling it within the same class.

Comment: methodFromClass1() is not static. You should create an Object of type CLass1 to call the method.

Comment: @Itnewbie - yes... read my post again please. Inside Class1 you do it the same way. you simply type `methodFromClass1();`

Comment: It fixed already. I called in inside the JContentPane. Thanks for the help